# Pushing to git with Personal Access Token is asking for password

Tags: linux, git, github, oauth, sh

I have a shell script file which will push the files to empty git repo.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://<my-personal-access-token>@github.com/<organization-name>/<repo-name>.git 
git push -u origin master
```

This was pushing files to repo without asking for password, but surprisingly now it is asking for password too.

[image]

Why is it asking for password even though I used personal access token? What is going wrong here?

Even if I input correct password manually, it says as below :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try below line in your code for git remote step by adding **username** to it:

```
git remote add origin https://username:<my-personal-access-token>@github.com/<organization-name>/<repo-name>.git
```

Comment: It is still get the same error : Invalid username or password